# Getting hashed Password from StandardProtectionPolicy before saving File - using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, optimization, hash, passwords, pdfbox

I'm working on a programm to bruteforce PDF-Files.

Now I can't read the hashed Owner-password before saving the PDDocument. The problem is that it is much slower to save the File again and again and again then just read out the hashed password from the StandardProtectionPolicy.

Here is my code which I'm working with.

```
//creating new Document
PDDocument doc1 = new PDDocument();

//creating StandardProtectionPolicy
StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("somepassword", "", new AccessPermission());
spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);

//setting the StandardProtectPolicy 
doc1.protect(spp);
doc1.save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\filename.pdf");

//reading out the hash
String hash = new String(doc1.getEncryption().getOwnerKey());

//closing the PDDocument
doc1.close();
```

So my question is, if I can read out the hash without saving or even creating the PDDocument. If I just don't save the document it don't work.

Thank you for your help.

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution.
So for other people who want to know it:

```
                    PDDocument doc1 = new PDDocument();
                    StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy(String.valueOf(i), "", new AccessPermission());
                    spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
                    doc1.protect(spp);
```

don't need to save anymore

```
                    //doc1.save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\working.pdf");

                    StandardSecurityHandler sh = new StandardSecurityHandler(spp);
                    sh.prepareDocumentForEncryption(doc1);

                    hash = new String(doc1.getEncryption().getOwnerKey());
```

Comment: It might be better to use `doc1.getEncryption().getSecurityHandler()`, then only one SecurityHandler object would be created, because `protect()` creates one too.